# Extracting Table name from an PL\SQL package or proceedure using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking to extract a list of all table names referenced in a Package or Procedure via the a saved '.sql' file. I know I can do this manually in notepad++ where I extract the next string after the following key_words like 'FROM' & 'JOIN' the script & then save it into another TXT file.

Cheers